# Asynchronous task on background

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

I am using asynchronous `NSURLConnection` to upload my images. I have a minor requirement and I want to know what is the efficient way to achieve it. When I press upload button then I pop my current view controller, so what I need is my upload operation keeps going on background even if I am at any part of my navigation controller stack. I can navigate and be anywhere but still want that upload to happen in background.

I just need tips on what is the efficient and elegant way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate your uploading logic from the view controller that triggers it.

Perhaps you could create an "upload manager" class that handles all the uploads from different view controllers in a queue and just notifies the interested view controllers about things like progress, errors, etc. (e.g. via notifications).

It could then also manage background task identifiers for continuing uploads when your app is sent to the background by pressing the home button.

Answer (score 3):

In this instance what you mean by "on background" is - on another thread. Thus you are talking about multithreading. Not to be confused with background processing which is in the case of iOS - tasks that execute while the application is in the background.

In order to do what you wish to do, I recommend using `GCD` (Grand Central Dispatch), you can `dispatch` a `block` of code to another thread (other then the main thread) in order to achieve a smooth "background like" processing - please remember that the main thread deals with everything UI related so, in order to not block it (literally) it is necessary to perform any long lasting processes such as downloading/uploading to and from remote sources on another thread.

This is an example of what you could so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // Prepare your upload request

    NSError * _urlError = nil;
    NSHTTPURLResponse * _responseHeaders = nil;
    NSData * responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:uploadHTTPRequest 
                                                  returningResponse:&_responseHeaders 
                                                              error:&_urlError];

    // by this line, we have a response
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Update UI or whatever, this is where you "rejoin" the main thread if needed.
        // Maybe for development, show a UIAlertView...
    });

});
```

Comment: Suppose i am running above code from one particular viewcontroller instance, if i navigate to other viewcontrollers by pushing or popping current, then it won't interfere with my connection right ? By background i meant separate thread and to keep it running irrespective of where i am at navigation stack. thanks

Comment: You don't need a separate thread to use `NSURLConnection` without blocking. The approach you're demonstrating here has the additional disadvantage that you cannot cancel any downloads as soon as they're running.

Comment: So if you run this code inside your UIViewController, if you navigate away from the view controller, this block will still execute, so will any of your UI related stuff in the final block to the main thread, basically Grand Central Dispatch is a technology which will queue tasks to be performed by the processor, it's goal is to smartly distribute these tasks in the most optimal way according to hardware available. It doesn't have anything to do with the UI, only threading. But ideally what you want to do is separate your network code from your view controller...

Comment: @omz - yes sure this won't let you easily cancel a request. This is just one of many options available.

Comment: @omz does it mean i dont need dispatch_async if i am using asynch nsurlconnection ? I can just make a upload call and task will proceed asynchromously and i can leave my viewcontroller ? Thanks.

Comment: If you already use an asynchronous URL connection, there's really no point in additionally wrapping that in `dispatch_async` (which can also get a bit complicated due to the runloop). You just don't want your view controller to be the connection's delegate if the upload should continue independent of the view controller.

Comment: @omz Thanks a lot. Just have a final query. I have just basic requirement as above. Right now my view controller is the delegate of nsurlconnection :D. Will it harm my app ? What is best thing i can do for just this requirement ?

Comment: You should really separate the view controller from the networking logic, imagine your view controller is deallocated, the NSURLConnections delegate will now be gone and could cause a crash when trying to message it.

Comment: Actually, `NSURLConnection` retains its delegate, so it wouldn't crash, but it's still definitely a good idea to separate view controllers from networking logic.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. So what shud i be doing is make a separate uploader class and make this class delegate of NSURLConnection. One more question, I will be making call from this new class object that i wrote. If view controller gets deallocate then wont my this new class object be also deallocated ?(this object being member of viewcontroller or shall i make static calls ?) Or this object will retained by my connection and i dont have to worry ? Thanks. Sorry for bothering u guys, i am still learning all this and need this concept to grasp.

Comment: One thing I like to do when I need an "API" class, is to implement the singleton design pattern, this lets me grab an instance at any time from anywhere, very handy for this kind of thing. @omz do you agree ?

Comment: Agreed, a singleton would be appropriate for something like this.